# Java alternative of javascript dynamically constructed object

Tags: java, object

I've been trying to build an object of some sort which allows dynamic key adding/removing, similar to javascript objects.

I'm trying to do something like this in java(code below is javascript):

```js
const object = {};
object["foo"] = "bar";
console.log(object);
// { "foo": "bar" };
delete object["foo"];
console.log(object);
// {};
```

I've tried doing:

```js
String[] arr;
arr["foo"]="bar";
```

Although that definitely won't work as "String cannot be converted to int".

Comment: You need a `Map`.

Comment: Hi, could you please comment your comment as an answer so I may flag it as correct, thank you very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050470/php-call-equivalent-for-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the Java equivalent of defining a classless object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65624689/whats-the-java-equivalent-of-defining-a-classless-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, the `Map` interface provides similar functionality. One such implementation is [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Its base class `AbstractMap` defines `#toString` in a way very similar to JavaScript:

```
final Map<String, Object> arr = new HashMap<>();
arr.put("foo", "bar");
System.out.println(arr);
arr.remove("foo");
System.out.println(arr);
```

Comment: well "similar" means `{world=the world, hello={one=1}, list=[1, 2], array=[I@58d25a40}` with maps and lists and better not with arrays. (`{ "world": "the world", "hello": { "one": "1" }, "list": [1, 2], "array": [1, 2] }` as json)